# Web2py how to store information NOT related to each particular user (global)

Tags: web2py

Web2py how to store information NOT related to each particular user (global)
For example: i want to fetch / cache  app general information

sessions vs  cached application item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is content that is generated dynamically and may potentially need to be refreshed, you can use the [cache](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#cache) mechanism. If it is just some fixed data that never changes (e.g., some application settings), you could just put it in a model file or a module (and import it).

Comment: Thanks (again) Anthony. (it sounds logical; have to read the web2py manual).